# Firebase Cloud messaging and Azure Notification Hub Error

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

I have a Xamarin for Visual Studio cross platform project and am getting an error trying to get notifications working using Azure Notifications Hub in the Android project. In the `FirebaseInstanceIdService-derived` class, I get an error when I try to instantiate a `NotificationHub` object. This is being called to register the user/device on Azure Notifications Hub.

```
NotificationHub hub = new NotificationHub(Constants.NotificationHubName, Constants.ListenConnectionString, this);
```

I usually get this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: Java.Lang.NullPointerException: occurred.
```

But have also received:

```
Unhandled Exception: Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference occurred.
```

I am calling this from a DependencyService that is invoked in the OnAppearing event of the Main Page. I can't rely on OnTokenRefresh() in the FirebaseInstanceIdService-derived class because I need the user to log in first.

I confirmed that the hub name and connection string are correct. And the context-related error certainly makes it seem related to this." But I'm not sure what the issue is since this is how it is handled in all the sample code I've seen.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

have you insert the following elements in the Manifest?

```
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
<receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
    <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Check out:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-push
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-push-notifications-android-gcm

Ps. Can you post other code? It could be useful to identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mikasa.  Here is the method:

```
//AuthenticatedUser is a class in the mobile app.

public void RegisterWithNotificationServer(AuthenticatedUser savedUser)
        {
            string token = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;

            string customerNotificationTag = "customerid:" + savedUser.CustomerNotificationTagID;
            string userNotificationTag = "userid:" + savedUser.UserNotificationTagID;

        //Hub variable defined with class scope.            
            hub = new NotificationHub(Constants.NotificationHubName, Constants.ListenConnectionString, this);

            List<string> tags = new List<string>() { customerNotificationTag, userNotificationTag };
            Registration registration = hub.Register(token, tags.ToArray());
            string regID = registration.RegistrationId;

        }
```

Comment: If you are storing the Hub Credentials in the Mobile app itself then its not a good idea to do that. All of your registration and sending the notifications should be behind your Web Api Services then Your app should consume the Web Service to get registered or send the notification using that.